# Injecting repository dependencies into a Unit of Work

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm trying to employ the Repository and Unit of Work patterns in my asp.net MVC project, however I'm having difficulty figuring out how to pass Repository dependencies to the Unit of Work. The general standard structure of the Unit of Work seems to be the following:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
 {
        private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

        public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._customerRepository == null)
                {
                    this._customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(someContext);
                }
                return _customerRepository;
            }
        }
}
```

Specifically, what's confusing me is this line:

`this._customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(someContext);`

By defining interfaces for repositories, isn't the whole idea about being able to inject Repository dependencies into the UoW as time progresses and business needs change? If so, why does almost every implementation I see online do the above? In this implementation how are we supposed to pass a new instance of `ICustomerRepository` to the UoW? Surely we would need to also change code in the UoW and isn't that against the open close principle? How would I inject repositories to my UoW?

I've look around SO, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791467/how-can-i-inject-the-repositories-to-the-unitofwork) seems to have been asked before, but I'm still having a hard time trying to understand the proposed solution (a facade service).

Comment: The proposed solution to the other question was to avoid referencing repositores inside the unit of work. The Facade Service was then introduced to solve a different problem, namely "Constructor Over-Injection". Where else did you see this implementation?

Comment: So the facade service is to address a totally different problem? The implementation i was talking about is the one in the code block in my question, [just like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13151312/189756), or dozens of other blog posts, articles and SO question addressing UoW and DI.

Comment: As far as I understand, yes. Interesting, I didn't know about these implementations, I always saw something along the lines of [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/182384).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways to get an instance of your CustomerRepository.
First approach is known as constructor injection which is a simple parameter in your constructur e.g.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _customerRepository = repository;
    }

    private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._customerRepository == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Missing repository");
            }
            return _customerRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

The second and more flexible way is to use an IoC Framework like Structuremap, Unity, Ninject... and so on.

Here's an example of Structuremap:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._customerRepository == null)
            {
                _customerRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomerRepository>();
            }
            return _customerRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionaly you need a configuraiton class to tell Structuremap which class to instantiate which could simply look like this:

```
public static class RepositoryRegistry
{
    internal static void DefaultConfiguration(Registry registry)
    {
       registry.For<ICustomerRepository>().Use<CustomerRepository>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. But how come almost all samples and articles online that claim to use repsoitory and UoW with DI tend to use the approach that I mentioned in my question, rather than the ones (more logical) suggested by you?

Comment: Maybe because they want their samples to keep as simple as possible

Comment: I would avoid the second suggestion as you end up with hidden dependencies on your IOC container as a service locator if you do that. Also in the first, I'd recommend doing the null check against the constructor argument rather than in the property getter since the UOW requires a repository, fail early & fail fast.

Comment: @Lukas Your solution looks good at first sight but one question, think in future everytime you are going to add new repository into your system, you need to change you UnitOfWork class as well. Isn't it?